# `fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME" (KeyError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, spree

I am using Spree 3.1. To use Heroku, I need AWS S3 tp store pictures. 
Spent so much time with KeyError both local and Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And like to share here:

1. In AWS S3 document to create IAM USER for ID and access_key_id and secret_access_key. To make it work, I need to create profile and set admin permission.
2. Only paste this in needs environment eg: config/environments/production.rb and development.rb

   ```
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      storage: :s3,
      s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
      }
     }
   ```

   Do not replace the value. Instead 
   For Heroku:

   ```
   heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your-bucket-name AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-access-key-id AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-secret-access-key AWS_REGION=your-region
   ```

And for local:
We add values in .env

```
    $ cat .env
     S3_BUCKET_NAME=your-bucket-name-development
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-access-key-id
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-secret-access-key
```

Don't "quote" those values

Comment: please merge this part into your question.

Comment: where does this .env file live?

Comment: the .env file is in the root of project (where Gemfile located)

Comment: The reason I didn't merge this part in the question is to follow the guide line to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
        access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
}
```

by

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
        s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
        access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        s3_region: ENV.fetch'AWS_REGION'],
    }
}
```